# Jquery template calling only once the function

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
  <tr class='title'>
       <th>Director </td>
       <th>Name </th></tr> 
  <tr class='title'>
       <td>${Name}</td>
       <td>${Director}</td></tr>

</script>

$( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies ).appendTo( "#movieList" );
```

In this template I want to call the header only once.
but because I am calling the template more than once it is calling all number of times and I am getting th printed multiple times.

I want to have this printed only once (executed):

```
<th>Director </td>
       <th>Name </th></tr>
```

how to do this with templates. am I missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the

```
<tbody id="movieList"></tbody>, I called

       <th> Director</th>.

Its like:

       <table>
       <th> Director </th>
   and than the template
```